# Helm install fails on K3s : ensure CRDs are installed first

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, envoyproxy, k3s

My team and I are new to Kubernetes and are experimenting with running a few applications on it.

For proof of concept, we have a running [Lightweight Kubernetes (K3s)](https://docs.k3s.io/) install, which presumably does not have the full range of CRDs available on a standard Kubernetes. While trying to install Envoy proxy via [Helm Chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/cloudnativeapp/envoy), we ran into the below error:

```
# helm install my-envoy cloudnativeapp/envoy --version 1.5.0
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: resource mapping not found for name: "my-envoy" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "PodDisruptionBudget" in version "policy/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first
```

Presumably the message `ensure CRDs are installed first` refers to components that are missing in K3s. Is there a way to get these components installed (via Helm or some other methods)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely the problem is not related to missing CRDs but to the kubernetes version. I assume you are using the latest K3S version, which is [v1.25.4](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/releases/tag/v1.25.4%2Bk3s1). `PodDisruptionBudget` was moved from `policy/v1beta1` to `policy/v1` in version [v1.25](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#poddisruptionbudget-v125). As the Envoy helm chart that you are using does not seem to be actively maintained, probably you will have to downgrade K3S or find a different chart.

Comment: Downgrading to k3s v1.24.8 did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/helm/helm-mapkubeapis may also help